# How can i go back to A from fragment B when I click on the toolbar back press?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

i am working on an app where I am using 4 fragments like A->B->C->D NOW I want that when back pressed(from the toolbar) from d it should go back to C AND on c back to b and so on. How can I achieve that I am completely new to android. Please guide me.

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [the *Navigation* Jetpack library](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) (which is a good idea at this point, it's basically standard) then that's the default behaviour, stepping back through all the moves you made, effectively undoing them.

If you're doing `FragmentTransaction`s by hand, then [here's the documentation for that](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#perform). Note the bit on `addToBackstack()`:

> Calling `addToBackStack()` commits the transaction to the back stack. **The user can later reverse the transaction** and bring back the previous fragment by pressing the Back button.

> **If you don't call `addToBackStack()` when you perform a transaction that removes a fragment**, then the removed fragment is destroyed when the transaction is committed, and **the user cannot navigate back to it**.

The Navigation library handles a lot of these details for you, and some other awkward stuff you'd have to watch out for and handle yourself. There's a bit to learn, but it's honestly pretty simple once you have the idea. If you're new to Android it's definitely worth learning! It's the modern and recommended way to handle navigation in an Android app (and you'll run into it a lot as a result)